# Nested Menu Item in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, jss

I have a problem in displaying the values from the TextField in my React app.
I'm using material UI and material-ui-phone-number as its packages. As you can see, the values after i click the flag, it is displaying on the back. I believe this is on the zIndex. Pls modify only the `dialog2.js`

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dialog-menuitem-dropdown-xumpj?file=/dialog2.js)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MuiPhoneNumber` utilizes a MUI modal for the country selection & its default `z-index` is `1300`. It does not look like they expose a prop to alter its css properties so you can just target `#country-menu` (the id of the modal) using any preferred styling solutions

```
<div>
  <style type="text/css">
    {`
    #country-menu {
      z-index: 1801;
    }
    `}
  </style>
  <DialogContent style={{ width: 300, height: 500 }}>
    <MuiPhoneNumber
      name="MobileNo"
      label="Mobile No."
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      defaultCountry={"vn"}
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={(e) => setSelectedValue(e)}
    />
  </DialogContent>
</div>
```

[image: Edit Nested Dialog MenuItem Dropdown (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for this! However in my app, it is still not overriding? Is there other way to do this?

Comment: Yes, (1) try ctrl+f5 to hard refresh the web page, (2) check the styles on dev tools for any other style that may be taking precedence - at that point just increase your CSS specificity if there are (e.g., `body #country-menu`)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by doing the following changes:

1. Remove all CSS z-index defined
2. Put the Dialog 2 in Dialog 1 content

Here is the working CSB Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-dialog-menuitem-dropdown-forked-wymm0?file=/dialog1.js

Comment: Thank you for this. But I'm sorry i forgot to tell that you should only modify on the `dialog2.js`. Other zIndex is fixed. Thank you

Comment: Hey I dont think this would be a really great solution as Dialog box itself define its own z-index and you are just overriding the default value, if you manage to solve this issue with z-index in near future it would cause a conflict if material-ui changes z-index or with a different element